# Finding a 'vector potential' such that $\mathbf E = \nabla\times \mathbf C$ for a point charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, vector-fields, point-particles

[Supposedly](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10522), "Any divergence-free vector field can be expressed as the curl of some other divergence-free vector field" over a simply-connected domain.

> So, what is one such vector potential which works for half of the Coulomb field?

To be clear, I want a vector potential whose curl equals the vector field $\mathbf R/|\mathbf R|^3$ for $z>0$ (for any $x$ and any $y$).
$\mathbf R$ is the position vector $(x,y,z)$.

I know the scalar potential method is usually used instead of this, but am curious about how ugly a
vector potential would look.  If this gets answered, it should then be easy to
answer [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308694).

Comment: This is mathematically the same as the question of how magnetic monopoles are constructed. See, for example, [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202841/distinction-of-dirac-monopole-and-polyakov-t-hooft-monopole) and references therein.

Comment: I think I'm asking for something different since I only want the monopole effects over half of space...I could not find the math which answers my question in the references, so please point me directly if I missed it.

Comment: The initial title is somewhat misleading - it leads one to expect a standard vector potential. I've edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

In cylindrical coordinates, this potential (pointed angularly about the z-axis) works:
$$\vec{C} = \frac{1-\frac{z}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}}{r} \hat{\phi} $$

By choice, the curl also contains an impulse along the singular line (x=0, y=0, z<0) to zero the divergence.  So, a solenoid sleeve from infinity can thereby generate the Coulomb field.  In hindsight, I guess this is obvious, but it's interesting to do away with electric monopoles and consider an electron to be tied to infinity (or maybe a nearby positron) this way.

Comment: Your expression is not clear, could you please edit it using MathJax for clarity (the SE standard for maths).  Thanks.